# Is there a way to restore a program that is "hidden in the system tray"?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to make a script that restores the window of applications like Process Explorer, TeamViewer, uTorrent, that minimize/hide to the system tray.

I've tried several things, and the most promising was the following:

```
function Set-WindowStyle {
    <#
    .LINK
    Original gist - https://gist.github.com/jakeballard/11240204
    #>

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'InputObject')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True, ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName = $True)]
        [Object[]] $InputObject,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [ValidateSet('FORCEMINIMIZE', 'HIDE', 'MAXIMIZE', 'MINIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 'SHOW', 'SHOWDEFAULT', 'SHOWMAXIMIZED', 'SHOWMINIMIZED', 'SHOWMINNOACTIVE', 'SHOWNA', 'SHOWNOACTIVATE', 'SHOWNORMAL')]
        [string] $Style = 'SHOW'
    )

    BEGIN {
        $WindowStates = @{
            'FORCEMINIMIZE'   = 11
            'HIDE'            = 0
            'MAXIMIZE'        = 3
            'MINIMIZE'        = 6
            'RESTORE'         = 9
            'SHOW'            = 5
            'SHOWDEFAULT'     = 10
            'SHOWMAXIMIZED'   = 3
            'SHOWMINIMIZED'   = 2
            'SHOWMINNOACTIVE' = 7
            'SHOWNA'          = 8
            'SHOWNOACTIVATE'  = 4
            'SHOWNORMAL'      = 1
        }

    $Win32ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); 
'@ -Name "Win32ShowWindowAsync" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru

    }

    PROCESS {
        foreach ($process in $InputObject) {
            $Win32ShowWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($process.MainWindowHandle, $WindowStates[$Style]) | Out-Null
            Write-Verbose ("Set Window Style '{1} on '{0}'" -f $MainWindowHandle, $Style)
        }
    }
}
```

The scripts works for other purposes (I can 'HIDE' a window just fine),

```
Get-Process TeamViewer | Set-WindowStyle -Style HIDE
```

but it seems that I can't restore a "minimized-to-tray" application sending combinations of 'SHOW', 'RESTORE' etc.

```
Get-Process TeamViewer | Set-WindowStyle -Style SHOW
Get-Process TeamViewer | Set-WindowStyle -Style RESTORE
```

Any ideas?

GIST: https://gist.github.com/lalibi/3762289efc5805f8cfcf

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$sw = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);
'@

$Proc = Get-Process TeamViewer | Select -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle
$type = Add-Type -Name ShowWindow2 -MemberDefinition $sw -Language CSharpVersion3 -Namespace Utils -PassThru
$type::ShowWindow($Proc, 3) # 3 = maximize 2 = Minimize
```

Comment: I've tried the `ShowWindow` from `user32.dll` before and unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Also @lalibi -- System Tray items have a 0 as the MainWindowHandle (they use the Desktop handle while hidden to the tray).  We need to find a way to get the app to restore itself, which clearly many "minimize to tray apps" can do.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it will suit to your particular case but try [windowhide](https://steve.fi/Software/windowhide/).

I used it some time ago to hide a particular on-top window from a batch file when I needed (it has a command line version) but the GUI will show lots of hidden windows in your system. You can then make appear any of them.

[image: WindowHide]

It includes source code so you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Useful perhaps but doesn't answer the question of doing it in code (PowerShell?).  Perhaps should be a direct comment as a workaround. Thx.